# What does zip do for loops

Tags: python-2.7

I want to understand the function of `zip`. If I have the following loop:

```
for input_value, time_diff in zip(mylist1, mylist2):
    # some stuff
```

Is it equivalent to:

```
for input_value in mylist1:
    for time_diff in mylist2:
         # some stuff
```

If so, it means it is just for compacting nested loops, isn't it?
Thank you

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. BTW, this method has documentation, with examples.

Comment: No, that would be `itertools.product`, not `zip`. Why not try them out and see?

Answer (score 0):

These are equivalent:

```
# assuming len(mylist1) == len(mylist2)
for i in range(len(mylist1)):
    input_value = mylist1[i]
    time_diff   = mylist2[i]
    # do stuff 

for input_value, time_diff in zip(mylist1, mylist2):
    # do stuff
```

zip like from a zipper . takes two (or more) lists and bundles them together by index. Look at the example in the docs. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> zipped
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```